# Python ast.literal_eval on dictionary string not working (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Tags: syntax-error

I am trying to process a dataset with JSON data. However, the data have been written on a file without being parsed. That means that a python dictionary is written in the file as a string instead of a JSON object as a string.

I've found a module (AST) that will do the job to convert the string to a dictionary again using the `ast.literal_eval` function.

However, I am getting a very strange error in some of the instances:

[image: Error when parsing using ast.literal_eval]

The code reads from a text file and apply the following to each line:

```
ast.literal_eval(line.rstrip())
```

It seems some of the characters are not ok with the AST module.

Need to recall as well that this is not happening with all the dataset, just with some instances.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try exploring the json package. It is cleaner and more standard way of converting strings to dictionary

```
json.loads(inputStr) // Converts string -> dict
json.dumps(inputJson) // Converts dict -> string
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Hi priyank. Thank you for your answer. However, that will not work. As I said in the post "data have been written on a file without being parsed". That means, someone wrote to the file a dict without being parsed to JSON before. Therefore, using `json.loads(inputStr)` will not work. That is why I need ast. literal_eval.